# (Ubuntu, apache2, ufw) https not reachable

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost, ufw

I am trying to run a webserver which should always redirect to https. If i set the http hosts to provide the documents and open the browser with http://domain.de it works, however if I open it with https://domain.de or if I enable the redirect, I always get a connection timeout, host unreachable. 
SSL mod is enabled. I can successfully do 'telnet localhost 443' on the host machine.
This is the current setup, which doesnt work:

domain.de.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.de
    ServerAlias www.domain.de
    Redirect / https://domain.de/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName shop.domain.de  
    Redirect / https://shop.domain.de/
</VirtualHost>
```

domain.de-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin contact@domain.de
            ServerName www.domain.de
            ServerAlias domain.de
            DocumentRoot /var/www/main

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin contact@domain.de
            ServerName shop.domain.de
            DocumentRoot /var/www/shop

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

netstat -tulpn:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29677/sshd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28342/apache2   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1719/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28342/apache2
```

ufw status:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

iptables -L -n:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
ufw-user-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
ufw-not-local  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that Ubuntus default rules disallow https and just adding ufw on top doesn't solve it. So what I did was, reset the whole iptable to a clean state and then setup ufw and enable the the protocols that I need. Now it's configured correctly and https is accessible.